# Host xyz.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Tags: dns

I have some problems with configuration of my DNS on VM...
When I'm trying to run command:
host dns.xyz.org
The error is Host xyz.org not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

**named.conf** looks like(the part of options not included):

```
view "internal"
{
match-clients { 172.16.0.0/24; 127/8; };
recursion yes;
    zone "." IN {
     type hint;
     file "/var/named/named.ca";
```

};
        include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

```
zone "xyz.org"{
     type master;
     file "internal/xyz.org";
     allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
     allow-query { 172.16.0.0/24; };
};

zone "0.16.172.in-addr.arpa" IN {
     type master;
     file "internal/172.16.0.rev";
     allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
     allow-query { 172.16.0.0/24; };
};

zone "101.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
     type master;
     file "internal/192.168.101.rev";
     allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
     allow-query { any; };
};
 };
 view "external"{

     match-clients { any; };
     recursion no;

     zone "xyz.org"{
         type master;
         file "external/xyz.org";
         allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
         allow-query { any; };
     };

     zone "101.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
         type master;
         file "external/192.168.101.rev";
         allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
         allow-query { any; };
     };
};
```

**resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 192.168.101.131
search xyz.org
```

**xyz.org**

```
$TTL 1D

 @ IN SOA dns.gsr2011.org. webmaster.gsr2011.org.(
   20101018    ; serial
   43200        ; refresh = 12 hours
   1800        ; retry = 30 minutes
   1209600        ; expire = 2 weeks
   86400);         ; minimum = 1 day

   IN     TXT    "Test"
   IN    NS     dns.xyz.org.
   IN     NS     dns2.xyz.org.
   IN     MX 10    smtp.xyz.org.
   IN    MX 20    mail.xyz.org.

pop        IN    CNAME    mail
imap        IN    CNAME    mail

bd        IN    CNAME    master
ldap        IN    CNAME    voyager

dns            IN     A    172.16.0.1
voyager        IN    A    172.16.0.2
master        IN    A    172.16.0.3
dns2        IN    A    192.168.101.132
mail        IN    A    192.168.101.3
smtp        IN    A    192.168.101.4
web        IN    A    192.168.101.5
```

Can you indicate me please maybe I'm missing something? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok everything is more easy than it seems :D!

I have changed 192.168.101.131 to 127.0.0.1 in this part:

```
zone "xyz.org"{
 type master;
 file "internal/xyz.org";
 allow-transfer { 192.168.101.131;192.168.101.132; };
 allow-query { 172.16.0.0/24; };
};
```

I also have removed:

```
zone "." IN {
 type hint;
 file "/var/named/named.ca";

};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
```

And that's it.